# Confused with usage of type parameter used in scala

Tags: scala

I have following simple code:

```
trait MyBox[T] {
  def capacity: Double
}

case class FruitBox[T](fruit: Int) extends MyBox[T] {
  override def capacity = 1.0
}


object FruitBox {
  def apply[T](fruit: Int): FruitBox[T] = new FruitBox[T](fruit)
}
```

The following code is also valid that I omit the type parameter `T`

```
case class FruitBox[T](fruit: Int) extends MyBox { //T is omitted for MyBox[T]
  override def capacity = 1.0
}


object FruitBox{
  def apply[T](fruit: Int): FruitBox[T] = new FruitBox(fruit) //T is omitted for new FruitBox
}
```

I would ask why I could omit the type parameter? What is the reason behind this?It looks to me that in scala，parameterized type must have type parameter to be a concrete type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to prevent a possible misunderstanding, this here does not compile:

```
trait MyBox[T] {
  def capacity: Double
}

case class FruitBox[T](fruit: Int) extends MyBox {
  override def capacity = 1.0
}
```

You can't omit `[T]` here, you would get "error: trait MyBox takes type parameters".

---

The second part of your question has nothing to do with `MyBox` or inheritance at all. This here would work in exactly the same way, for exactly the same reasons:

```
case class FruitBox[T](fruit: Int)

object FruitBox{
  def apply[T](fruit: Int): FruitBox[T] = new FruitBox(fruit)
}
```

The type parameter can be omitted from the code, but the expression `new FruitBox(fruit)` on the right hand side is *still of the right type* `FruitBox[T]`. This is because the return type `FruitBox[T]` can be used to *infer* the type of the expression that comes after the `=`-sign. The compiler adds the `[T]` automatically, so that the above definition is just a short form of

```
def apply[T](fruit: Int): FruitBox[T] = new FruitBox[T](fruit)
```

This is similar to the following example:

```
var foo: Set[String] = Set.empty
```

Even though the method `empty` is again parameterized by a type, this type parameter can be inferred from the type of the declared variable, so that the code effectively becomes:

```
var foo: Set[String] = Set.empty[String]
```

---

Type inference would kick in in several other cases, most prominently:

- When the expression `new FruitBox(i)` appears as an argument to a method that requires an argument of type `FruitBox[SomeType]` at that position, then the compiler will automatically infer that `new FruitBox(i)` actually stands for `new FruitBox[SomeType](i)`.
- When you use type ascription: In `(new FruitBox(42) : FruitBox[String])`, the compiler will automatically add `[String]` to the `new` invokation.